# When I enable "WaylandEnable=false" option in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file to enable screen sharing 3 fingers gestures on track pad stop working 22LTS?

Tags: touchpad, screen, gestures

When I enable "WaylandEnable=false" option to enable screen sharing in google meet my touch pad's 3 fingure gestures stop working.

Comment: It is expected. What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

As you observe. Advanced touchpad features are a feature, and one of the advantages to move to Wayland. There are also possibilities that are lacking (e.g. global application hotkeys, control on windows placement, classical screen recoding tools that do not anymore work, ...) that cause other users (mainly power users) to continue preferring Xorg for now.

There are some Gnome Shell extensions, e.g. [X11 Gestures](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4033/x11-gestures/) by JoseExposito, that implement or change gestures on Xorg, but this still may not work as fluently and seamless as on Wayland.